# How to create a confidence interval for a weighted average of areas under the ROC curve in r?

Tags: r

What I have is a vector with different areas under the ROC curve (of different studies), e.g,

`a <- c(.91, .85, .76, .89)`

I also have the absolute number of participants in each study, e.g.,

`n <- c(50, 34, 26, 47)`

I calculated the weighted average for the areas with

`weighted.mean(a, n)`

Is there a way in R to also calculate the 95% confidence intervals of the weighted mean, based on the information I have? I looked into `pROC`, but as far as I understood it, there you need the raw data for each ROC curve (which I don't have). I would be very thankful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 8):

```
weighted.ttest.ci <- function(x, weights, conf.level = 0.95) {
    require(Hmisc)
    nx <- length(x)
    df <- nx - 1
    vx <- wtd.var(x, weights, normwt = TRUE) ## From Hmisc
    mx <- weighted.mean(x, weights)
    stderr <- sqrt(vx/nx)
    tstat <- mx/stderr ## not mx - mu
    alpha <- 1 - conf.level
    cint <- qt(1 - alpha/2, df)
    cint <- tstat + c(-cint, cint)
    cint * stderr
}

> weighted.ttest.ci(a,n)
[1] 0.7696 0.9627
```

Comment: This does provide a weighted t-test. but does nothing to address the request for a weighted AUC. That's not to say that a weighted AUC actually sounds like a good idea .... it actually sounds like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: @42 It's the CI for a weighted mean of the different areas under the ROC curve he or she reported (using a function originally written for a t.test but identical to what I got with the `weights` package weighted mean), weighting them in the way the OP specified.

Comment: I don't know about the ROC curve, but I used the function to get confidence intervals for sample means from weighted data and it worked like a charm after adding `na.rm=T` in the `weighted.mean` command.